# LESS: passing ruleset (or mixin) with variables to another mixin and be able to use these variables

Tags: variables, namespaces, less, parameter-passing, mixins

I want to pass mixin with varialbles to another mixin as a parameter and use these variables there (in another mixin). But it looks like less doesn't see these variables. Any ideas? thank you:

```
// Using ruleset with vars
@btn4: {
  @bg: { background: #98b501; };
};
._btn(@vars) {
  @vars();
  @bg();
}
.button {
  ._btn(@btn4);
}

// Using mixin with vars
._btn4() {
  @bg: { background: #98b501; };
};
._btn(@vars) {
  @vars();
  @bg();
}
.button {
  ._btn({ @btn4(); });
}
```

**I've got error:**
variable @bg is undefined

**But this works:**

```
// Using mixin with vars
._btn4() {
  @bg: { background: #98b501; };
};
._btn() {
  ._btn4();
  @bg();
}
.button {
  ._btn();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the "detached ruleset" (this is typically used codename for that `@var: {};` feature) is not considered to be a mixin and thus it does not have all mixin properties and behavior. Including the possibility of exposing its internally defined variables to a caller scope. So no, by now `@vars();` does not make `@bg` to be visible in `._btn`. (there's ongoing discussion of this possibility to be allowed but it was no consensus yet). *However* the "detached ruleset" *does* expose its internally defined mixins to the caller scope (and indeed now that looks confusing all together :) so you can achieve the same if you change `bg` to a plain mixin, e.g.:

```
@btn4: {
    .bg() {background: #98b501}
};

._btn(@vars) {
    @vars();
    .bg(); // OK
}

.button {
    ._btn(@btn4);
}
```

In certain cases it would be even more handy to keep `btn4` as mixin too and only wrap it into a detached ruleset right at the point of passing to another mixin, e.g.:

```
.btn4() {
    .bg() {background: #98b501}
}

._btn(@vars) {
    @vars();
    .bg();
}

.button {
    ._btn({.btn4}); // wrap
}
```

In this case the `.btn4` actually becomes a namespace (since its parens are optional and maybe omitted) which may lead to a bit more solid/organized/readable structure in a long run (also giving a bonus of possibility to call `.btn4.bg()` (aka `.btn4 > .bg()`) directly).